# Starting a new campaign with basic weapons

Tags: resident-evil-6

I completed Resident Evil 6 on normal mode, all 4 chapters (pretty poorly, I might add) and am now going back through the game to achieve S rank on all chapters. When I went to start a new game it asked if I wanted to start a new game using previous weapons. Having pressed 'yes', I'm now on Leon's chapter 1 and only have the Wingshooter and knife.. I've also bought the infinite shotgun skill but have no shotgun to use it :( any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that is not what it says. If you read it carefully then you will find out that you actually need to press "No" to start with all your previous weapons (I cannot remember the exact text at the moment).

I admit I found the text to be a bit misleading too, so I can see how it could easily be overlooked.

It's also worth mentioning that replaying the campaign with the "other" character, does not allow use of weapons collected from the first playthrough, ie. you have to collect each characters weapons individually.

Comment: thanks for answering. I have started a new campaign with chris and he seems to have all his old weapons. So, does this mean having already started with leon previously that he will only have his original weapons? Also, to use infinite shotgun do you have to achieve an S grade in a particular chapter in order to use it?

Comment: @nardo6890: I am not sure you can restart with leon and re-use weapons until you complete again. But as you have infinite shotgun ammo you should be ok as you get this weapon earlier in Leon's campaign. To enable it you need to purchase the skill, asign it to a skill slot, and make sure you have that skill slot selected in your game. you also MUST enable "infinite ammo" on the "network settings" screen when you load a save game

Comment: aw man, thats a gutter! thank you for your help, i'll get right on it ;)